# Vue router in main.js: this dependency was not found error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

When I run `npm run serve` I get the `This dependency was not found` error, relating to the `router` that I'm trying to use in the `main.js`. I don't understand why this happens - the router is created and exported from `src/router/router/js` file and imported in the `main.js` file.

**main.js**:

```
import App from './App.vue'
import './assets/tailwind.css'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import router from 'router/router.js'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const app = new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')

app.use(router);
```

**router.js**:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import About from '../views/About.vue'

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/home',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '/about',
        name: 'About',
        component: About
    }
]
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes
})
export default router
```

This is my directory structure:

[image]

I get this error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* router/router.js in ./src/main.js
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not imported the router correctly, it should be like this instead:

```
import router from './router/router.js'
```

Normally it should work now.

Edit:

Try making a new vue project with the router preset.

Comment: Same error. Please see picture with directory structure.

Comment: Ok, I think you have to remove the two dots, if you try it, it should work now. If this still doesn't work, you can try creating a new vue project with vue-router as a preset

Answer (score 0):

I change import to

```
import router from `./router/router.js
```

And also made new project with Vue 3 (was used Vue 2 for this one), where I installed `vue-router@next`. Then I followed this tutorial: https://www.vuemastery.com/blog/vue-router-a-tutorial-for-vue-3/

Changed `main.js`:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router/router.js'

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```